# DataTable LINQ Join C#

Tags: c#, linq, join, datatable

I have the following tables (DataTable):

**`CallData`** table has fields `Strike`, `MidPrice` and **`PutData`** table with fields `Strike` and `Midprice` I would like to join them on `Strike` and choose minimum of the following expression:

```
Abs(CallData.MidPrice - PutData.MidPrice)
```

Here is how I image it should look in LINQ terms:

```
var result = (from CallRow in CallData.AsEnumerable()
              join PutRow in PutData.AsEnumerable()
                on CallRow.Field<int>("Strike") equals PutRow.Field<int>("Strike") 
            select new { Abs(CallRow.Field<double>("MidPrice")
                             - PutRow.Field<double>("MidPrice"))
                       }).Min();
```

However, expression

```
 Abs(CallRow.Field<double>("MidPrice")
```

is underlined by wavy line and the message says:

> Invalid anonymous type member declared. Anonymous type member must be declared with a member
>   assignment simple name or member access.

Any ideas how to correct it?

EDIT: Great answer Selman22! I have found the following example in [link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1893115593)

```
static void GetNameAndDescription {ProductInfo[] products}
{
Console.WriteLine("Names and Descriptions:")
var nameDesc = from p in product select new {p.Name, p.Description};
}
```

Do you know why this code is valid with 'new'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't even need an anonymous type here. Just remove the `new` part

```
var result = (from CallRow in CallData.AsEnumerable()
          join PutRow in PutData.AsEnumerable()
          on CallRow.Field<int>("Strike") equals PutRow.Field<int>("Strike") 
          select Abs(CallRow.Field<double>("MidPrice") 
                    - PutRow.Field<double>("MidPrice"))).Min();
```

The error message explains the reason clearly:

> Anonymous type member **must be declared with a member assignment** simple name or member access.

In this case you have a complex expression, so you need to set the value to a property to make it work. like `new { value = Abs(...) }`, but as I said already you don't need it...

Comment: Thank you very much! One quick question. In [link](http://www.amazon.com/C-NET-Platform-Andrew-Troelsen/dp/1893115593) there is following example: ''